# Sort a list of strings, but in int order

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

i have a list that is list = [3, 25, 1]
But when i use list.sort(), the output is [1,25,3]
I suppose it take it as a string, and order them by their first character...
How do i make it sort them by the int order?
It is in python 3

Comment: Please show your code this far

Comment: sorry, it is in python 3, i am a little new in this page :)

Comment: `sorted(lst)`.  Don't use `list` as a variable.